# Cache XML File Java

Tags: java, xml, caching

I am trying to Cache a XML File on application initialization. What would be the best approach  to do it?

Which would be the most efficent datastructure which I can use? The datastructure should be efficent in lookups.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to cache the contents of the XML file, and not a reference to the file. You would first parse the XML, and then you could go a couple of ways. One way to do this would be to map the XML to a (object tree of) Java class, and then cache the Java class. You can use [Castor](http://www.castor.org/) or some [JAXB](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/) library to do this. If your XML has a set of repeating nodes, you can consider an in-memory database to query on, such as [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/). HyperSQL would allow you to use plain SQL for lookups.